# How do I know if mudguards will fit my 2009 Carrera Kraken?

Tags: mountain-bike, accessories, fenders

With the nice (and muddy!) weather coming up, I'd like to get some mudguards, but I'm really unsure of what will fit my bike

I have a [2009 Carrera Kraken](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_518229_langId_-1_categoryId_165499), no modifications.

I will probably buy them from ebay since there are cheap ones on there, which fittings/style of mudguard are good?

Comment: Mud guards only, or fenders with mud guards?

Comment: Related: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/will-the-topeak-fx-rx-mudguards-fit-a-carerra-kraken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your bike I would probably recommend a 'moto style' front fender that uses an expansion fitting in the steerer tube to remain fixed in place. My reason being that it does not look like you have eyelets on that fork for easy full fender installation.

http://bontrager.com/model/06254

A seatpost clamp style rear fender is my recommendation. Again, it looks like a full fender set w/ struts would be difficult to mount to your bike (not impossible, just a little finicky) and quite frankly, it would look a wee bit weird to put a full fender on the rear and a moto style on the front. Just sayin'.

http://bontrager.com/model/06255

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is worth paying the higher price at a local bike shop to get good advice.

Any reasonable bike shop will be able to look at your bike and tell you what will fit.

The change for fitting is also likely to be low, and getting the shop to do the fitting removes the risk of them claiming they do fit, and you saying they don’t.

Comment: Ps,I would not consider halfords to be bike shop, find a good shop that has staff that know about bikes for this sort of thing.