# Will the topeak FX & RX mudguards fit a Carerra kraken?

Tags: accessories, fenders, topeak

I have [this](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_518229_langId_-1_categoryId_165499) bike

Will [these mudguards](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/Mudguard-Topeak-Defender-Mudguard-FX-RX-FRT-REAR-/390221003211?pt=UK_sportsleisure_cycling_bikeparts_SR&hash=item5adafbf9cb) fit OK?

I don't know much about fittings, but there is a picture on the bike link.

Comment: Related: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-do-i-know-if-mudguards-will-fit-my-2009-carrera-kraken

Comment: URL not found for the bike. The mudguard link goes to a non-existent Ebay listing. You need to fix the links before anyone can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Topeak website, the front one attaches like this:

[image]

and the rear one like this (onto the seatpost):

[image]

so it's likely they'll both fit.

A search for the Topeak FX Mudguard on Google Shopping gives me various ones at less than £9 as does the Topeak RX Mudguard. This place [allterraincycles.co.uk](http://www.allterraincycles.co.uk/m/4_Clothing%2Band%2BAccessories/1_Accessories/16_Mudguards%2B%2526%2BFenders/311_Topeak/) appears to have both the front and rear in stock and will charge you 2 quid less including delivery, than the ebay one you're looking at.

Comment: Just for the record, the front one: both parts of the mudguard are detatchable, the fixing screws up into the suspension tube as you can see on the picture above. As you tighten the allen screw it expands for a tight fitting. Then you just clip the front/back parts on.

Comment: The rear one clips around the seatpost, there is a strap which latches on and you tighten it and clip it back, seems solid enough